# Update Textbox Values in the Same Class

Tags: jquery, textbox, auto-update

I have a table which includes a series of textboxes which are dynamically created and populated.  I would like to add some jQuery which, if 3 is entered into a set of textboxes (defined by a class), that the other textboxes in this class will default to zero.

But if any other value is entered, then to allow this value.  I have started with the following jQuery code:

```
$(".TABval1").change(function(){
    $(".TABval1").not(this).val(0);
});
```

I have created a [jsFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hkhUQ/1/) to demonstrate.

Comment: Where is the rest of the code in your jsFiddle?

Comment: I've just taken an extract of my code for the fiddle.  My jQuery knowledge would not be the greatest.

Comment: I will suggest you to use .live() or .delegate() method in place of .change() method for dynamically created controls. See the link for reference: http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html

Comment: @DustinCook Try `$(document).on('change','.TABval1', function(){ $(".TABval1").not($(this)).val(0); });`

Comment: @DustinCook Did you try it? We need whatever code generates the checkboxes or we can't test it.

Comment: Yes I tried it - but it did not work.  When I said that it is dynamically populated, I just meant that the code creates the table and populates it as a normal HTML page.  My code above works after the page has loaded, were the user selects which items they require processing.

Comment: Could something like this work?  `$($(.TAB1val1).val() == 3).change(function(){ $(".REAL_PWR1").not(this).val(0);});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work a solution to this - just in case anyone needs this in the future:

```
$(".TAB1val1").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 3) {
        $(".TAB1val1").not(this).val(0);
    }
});
```

[And the updated fiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/hkhUQ/5/)